# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "absolute_redirect"

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
...
server {
  expires off;
  absolute_redirect off;

  listen       8080;
  server_name  localhost;

  # listen 80 default_server;
  # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  # listen 443 ssl;

  client_body_timeout 36s;
  client_header_timeout 36s;
  keepalive_timeout 36s;
  send_timeout 36s;
  ....
```

this config cannot pass the test `service nginx configtest`.
Command `nginx -t` show me the following:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "absolute_redirect" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What is wrong with `absolute_redirect`?

NB: nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Google first hit http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect says "This directive appeared in version 1.11.8."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault, I used an old version of nginx. `absolute_redirect` is supported only since nginx 1.118